# Hibernate get method returns old version of record in thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-applications

We have java web application, we are using spring, hibernate3 and I have problem with getting actual version of record from DB.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Class Scheduler
{
    public void scheduleTests(………….)
    {
    .
    .
    .
    TestCase testCase;
    .
    //Updating entity
    getHibernateTemplate ().saveOrUpdate(testCase);
    getHibernateTemplate ().flush();
    .
    .
    .
    Starts new thread
    .
}

Thread run{
    .
    .
    TestCase testCase = getTestCase(testCaseId);
    .
    .
    .
    .
    updateTestCase(testCase);
}

getTestCase(testCaseId)
{
    TestCase testCase = null;
    try
    {                       
        testCase=(TestCase)getHibernateTemplate().get(TestCase.class, testCaseId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return testCase;
}

updateTestCase(TestCase testCase)
{
    try
    {
       getHibernateTemplate ().saveOrUpdate(testCase);
       getHibernateTemplate ().flush();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In method schedule test I change the object TestCase and after it is saved into DB. Then new thread starts, and in the beginning of this thread I ask DB for actual version of TestCase from DB. Then some functionality is executed and in the end status of TestCase is updated to DB.

Problem is when I run this scenario more than 1 times. Then weird thing happened. In thread method run I got from method getTestCase old version of TestCase and then update crashes with following exception:

ERROR

```
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:300) - Could not synchronize database state with session
"org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [at.h3g.portal.db.webshop.WsRcCheck#405]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1680)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2180)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2456)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:988)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$29.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:815)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:366)
    at org.springframework.
ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:300) - Could not synchronize database state with session
"org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [at.h3g.portal.db.webshop.WsRcCheck#405]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1680)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2180)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2456)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:988)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:500)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:473)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.doCommitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:170)
```

Why I got old version of TestCase? What could I do?
Here is configuration of Hibernate and Spring.

In Web.Xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

And context configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
        .
        .
        .
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">
                auto
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/SOMEDATASOURCE</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="hibernateTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionInterceptorTestScheduling"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <value>                 org.company.db.Scheduler.updateTestCase=PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I want to add, there is only one thread created in that time, and nothing else access TestCase data in database. Only problem is that getTestCase returns old version of TestCase record, and I don't now why.

Thank you for advice.

Comment: Only a guess. Try to wrap save and get by separate transactions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the hibernate session is bounded to the current thread. So one solution is don't use threads or there should be created transaction interceptor, which will take care about sessions for threads. See more on [Spring How to get bean with prototype scope from ProxyFactoryBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434799/spring-how-to-get-bean-with-prototype-scope-from-proxyfactorybean)