# Spring How to get bean with prototype scope from ProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring

I stuck with this problem.

Used components: Spring 1.2.8, Hibernate 3.2.0 cr1, tomcat, struts, java 6

I am trying to get bean from ProxyFactoryBean with scope = prototype. I am not successful. I have no clue what is wrong.

Here is context:

```
<beans>

    <bean id="ruleCheckTask" class="rulechecker.RuleCheckTask" singleton="false">

    <bean id="ruleCheckTaskPrototype" class="org.springframework.aop.target.PrototypeTargetSource">
       <property name="targetBeanName" value="ruleCheckTask" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionInterceptorRuleCheckTask" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor .TransactionInterceptor">
       <property name="transactionManager"> 
           <ref bean="transactionManager" />
       </property>
       <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
          <value>
              rulechecker.IRuleCheckTask.run=PROPAGATION_REQUIRE S_NEW
          </value>
       </property>
   </bean>

  <bean id="ruleCheckTaskService" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFact oryBean">
         <property name="target" ref="ruleCheckTaskPrototype" />
         <property name="proxyInterfaces">
             <value>
                  rulechecker.IRuleCheckTask
             </value>
        </property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
              <list>
                   <value>transactionInterceptorRuleCheckTask</value>
              </list>
        </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

In code when I do following:

...................

...................

IRuleCheckTask checkTask = (IRuleCheckTask) applicationContext.getBean("ruleCheckTaskService") ;
checkTask.setTestCase(oneTestCase);

I got following exception when trying call setTestCase on checkTask bean:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nativ e Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknow n Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Un known Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoi npointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:287)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethod  Invocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocat ion.java:181)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethod    Invocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java :148)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.Transa ctionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.jav a:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethod Invocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java :170)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopPro xy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:176)
at $Proxy21.setTestCase(Unknown Source)
```

It was working if in ProxyFactoryBean I used ruleCheckTask instead ruleCheckTaskPrototype. Problem is that in that case I always obtain singleton of ruleCheckTask. And I need always new instance.
One small thing RuleCheckTask implements Runnable interface.

Could anybody give me a hint?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
<bean id="ruleCheckTaskService" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFact oryBean">
         <property name="targetName" value="ruleCheckTask" />
         <property name="singleton" value="false" />  <!-- this do the trick -->
         <property name="proxyInterfaces">
             <value>
                  rulechecker.IRuleCheckTask
             </value>
        </property>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
              <list>
                   <value>transactionInterceptorRuleCheckTask</value>
              </list>
        </property>
   </bean>
```

You could also set `targetSource` (no `target`) to `ruleCheckTaskPrototype` instead.  The diference is that on the first one, you have an independient instance of the proxy configuration, on the second one, the `PrototypeTargetSource` gets a new instance on each request.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It is really working.                                                                 I made mistakes, I put singleton property directory into declaration <bean singleton=false>, and I got exception, that ProxyFactoryBean has to be singleton. And second mistake from my side was, I specified target through property "target" and "ref" instead of "targetName" and "value". What a small details and they are important. It is not easy to get this information. How do you know that? Where did you learn this stuff? Could you recommend some good book, ebook, link about spring? Thank you

Comment: There are good books from spring source team and others, and spring have a really good reference documentation. But when you gets a problem like this, the best way is link the source code to the library and jump inside. Most times you will spend less time to find the correct path. For example, if you put a breakpoint on ProxyFactoryBean.getObject() the solution is clear. Use the source, luke... (UTSL)